# Why is 'that' in 'beyond that of"?

Tags: grammar

Why is 'that' in 'beyond that of"? I think it is clear without 'that'. Can we  omit 'that' here?

> The nature of peace-keeping operations had evolved rapidly and
>   expanded beyond **that** of traditional military observer missions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comparison in this sentence. The two things being compared are:

1. The nature of peace keeping operations.
2. The nature of traditional military observer missions.

It is the "nature of" the thing that is being referred to in both cases. Instead of using "nature" twice in the sentence, the author uses the word "that" for the second instance. This is a common stylistic substitution.